# Can someone explain waveshaping to me?

Tags: transfer-function, distortion

Can someone explain waveshaping to me?

I only know it shapes waveshapes by passing through some functions, but I don't yet understand e.g. what the plots (such as the following in Melda Production MWaveShaper VST-plugin) mean.

[image]

Both axes have dB values so I read the axes to be input and output. However, how is the distortion "visualized" in the graph? How does one know how the graph alters audio?

Comment: It's quite frankly simply an input/output mapping, so: not quite sure what your question is, here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So does a waveshaper work by mapping input amplitudes to new output amplitudes and thus the waveform becomes distorted (through this logic)? But I guess that it's impossible to predict from the graph, what the output will sound like?

Comment: yes, that's how I understand it. "Impossible" is a strong word. It *will* sound distorted, and an experienced person might have an idea how it sounds like. But "how it sounds" is more of an *aesthetic* or *artistic* or *psychological* aspect, which can really only hardly be pressed into terms of signal processing.

Comment: there are some things you can discern about what the output might sound like given a polynomial waveshaping function.

Answer (score 5):

In the audio domain, waveshaping is simply applying a memoryless nonlinear function to an input signal.

$$ y(t) = g\big( x(t) \big) $$

The waveshaping function, $g(x)$, is most often a continuous function that goes through the origin: $g(0)=0$.

Sometimes $g(x)$ is an odd-symmetry function: $g(-x)=-g(x)$, but it doesn't have to be.  Sometimes you want 2nd harmonic distortion and then $g(x)$ does not have odd symmetry.

I am more interested in the case where the waveshaping function, $g(x)$ is a polynomial of finite order $N$:

$$ g(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,x^n $$

Note that if $g(x)$ has even symmetry ($g(-x)=g(x)$), then all odd terms are zero ($a_n=0$ for $n$ odd).  If $g(x)$ has odd symmetry ($g(-x)=-g(x)$), then all even terms are zero ($a_n=0$ for $n$ even).  I guess, if you want $g(0)=0$, then $a_0=0$.

Now, if the input is sinusoidal:

$$ x(t) = A \cos(2 \pi f_0 t) $$

then the output is periodic, having harmonic frequency components, with an upper limit to the frequency content.  The highest frequency coming out will be $N f_0$.  So waveshaping with polynomial mapping functions guarantees a limit to the highest frequencies generated and that can be useful in deciding an oversampling ratio necessary to guard against aliasing.  As I alluded to in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/monotonic-symmetrical-soft-clipping-polynomial/36204#36204), if the order of the polynomial is $N$, to insure against aliases folding back into your original passband, one must oversample with an upsampling ratio of at least $\frac{N+1}{2}$.  Oversampling by 4x sufficies for a 7th-order polynomial.

Also note that an even-symmetry polynomial will generate only even harmonics and an odd-order polynomial will generate only odd harmoncs.

$$\begin{align}
y(t) &= g\big( x(t) \big)  \\ 
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\big(x(t)\big)^n \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\big(A \cos(2 \pi f_0 t)\big)^n \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} b_k \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t) \\
\end{align}$$

where the $b_k$ coefficients depend on the $a_n$ coefficients and the input amplitude of $A$.  This relationship can be worked out using the Euler identity and the binomial theorem:

$$\begin{align}
y(t) &= g\big( x(t) \big)  \\ 
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\big(A \cos(2 \pi f_0 t)\big)^n \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}(e^{j 2 \pi k f_0 t}+e^{-j 2 \pi k f_0 t})\right)^n \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n\left(e^{j 2 \pi f_0 t}+e^{-j 2 \pi f_0 t}\right)^n \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} (e^{j 2 \pi f_0 t})^m (e^{-j 2 \pi f_0 t})^{n-m}  \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} e^{j 2 \pi m f_0 t} e^{-j 2 \pi (n-m) f_0 t}  \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n \tfrac12 \left(\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} e^{j 2 \pi m f_0 t} e^{-j 2 \pi (n-m) f_0 t} \\ + \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} e^{j 2 \pi m f_0 t} e^{-j 2 \pi (n-m) f_0 t} \right)  \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n \tfrac12 \left(\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} e^{j 2 \pi m f_0 t} e^{-j 2 \pi (n-m) f_0 t} \\ + \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} e^{j 2 \pi (n-m) f_0 t} e^{-j 2 \pi m f_0 t} \right)  \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n \tfrac12 \left(\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} e^{j 2 \pi (2m-n) f_0 t} + \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} e^{j 2 \pi (n-2m) f_0 t} \right)  \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n \tfrac12 \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} \left( e^{j 2 \pi (n-2m) f_0 t} + e^{-j 2 \pi (n-2m) f_0 t} \right)  \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n  \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} \tfrac12 \left( e^{j 2 \pi (n-2m) f_0 t} + e^{-j 2 \pi (n-2m) f_0 t} \right)  \\
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} a_n\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^n \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} \cos \big(2 \pi (n-2m) f_0 t \big)  \\
\\
...
\\
 &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} b_k \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t) \\
\end{align}$$

Okay, to get an expression for $b_k$, the only way I can figger it out is for three cases.  We let $k=n-2m$ and observe that since $2m$ is always even, only even $n$ terms contribute to $b_k$ when $k$ is even.  Likewise, only odd $n$ terms contribute to $b_k$ when $k$ is odd.

The expression $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$ is the `floor()` function applied to $N/2$.  just round $N/2$ down to the nearest integer.

**Case 1**, $k=0$ (the DC term)
Only the even terms of $n$ will contribute to $b_0$.  And the only term of the inside summation that contributes is that when $m=\tfrac{n}{2}$.  So letting $n=2i$:

$$ b_0 = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} a_{2i}\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^{2i} \frac{(2i)!}{\big((i)!\big)^2} $$

In the following two cases, keep in mind that the $\cos()$ function is even symmetry and these two terms are equal:

$$ \cos(2 \pi (-k) f_0 t) = \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t) $$

**Case 2**, $k$ even, $k>0$ (even harmonics)
Only the even terms of $n$ will contribute to $b_k$.  The only two term of the inside summation that contribute are those where $m=\tfrac{n-k}{2}$ and $m=\tfrac{n+k}{2}$ .  So letting $n=2i$:

$$ b_k = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} a_{2i}\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^{2i} \frac{2(2i)!}{(i-\tfrac{k}{2})!(i+\tfrac{k}{2})! } \qquad k>0 \text{ even} $$

Terms with $i<\tfrac{k}{2}$ will result in $\infty$ in the denominator because factorials of negative integers are infinite.  That effectively modifies the bottom limit:

$$ b_k = \sum\limits_{i=k/2}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} a_{2i}\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^{2i} \frac{2(2i)!}{(i-\tfrac{k}{2})!(i+\tfrac{k}{2})! } \qquad k>0 \text{ even} $$

**Case 3**, $k$ odd, $k>0$ (odd harmonics)
Only the odd terms of $n$ will contribute to $b_k$.  The only two term of the inside summation that contribute are those where $m=\tfrac{n-k}{2}$ and $m=\tfrac{n+k}{2}$.  So letting $n=2i+1$:

$$ b_k = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor (N-1)/2 \rfloor} a_{2i+1}\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^{2i+1} \frac{2(2i+1)!}{(i-\tfrac{k-1}{2})!(i+\tfrac{k+1}{2})!} \qquad k>0 \text{ odd} $$

Terms with $i<\tfrac{k-1}{2}$ will result in $\infty$ in the denominator because factorials of negative integers are infinite.  That effectively modifies the bottom limit:

$$ b_k = \sum\limits_{i=(k-1)/2}^{\lfloor (N-1)/2 \rfloor} a_{2i+1}\,\left(\tfrac{A}{2}\right)^{2i+1} \frac{2(2i+1)!}{(i-\tfrac{k-1}{2})!(i+\tfrac{k+1}{2})!} \qquad k>0 \text{ odd} $$

.

(i wouldn't mind if someone else checked my math.  these results tell us *something* about how a polynomial waveshaping function will sound, at least what the amplitude of harmonics will be.)

Comment: See how posts pile up lines when you enjoy the subject?

Comment: hay @A_A, wanna check my work?  (for the 3 cases?)  i am not perfectly confident i did it correctly and am too lazy to code up MATLAB to check a few examples.

Comment: It is the end of the day in my timezone so I am going to go "pass" for the moment. But I am very interested in the impact of that function composition there, especially when the shaping is through a polynomial, so, I will definitely come back to take a second look at this, not necessarily with a critical eye. If I spot anything too much out of line I will let you know.

Comment: cool.  i just read a mistake that i am going to correct right now.